# How can I run my python script from the terminal in Mac OS X without having to type the full path?

Tags: python, macos, path, terminal

I'm on Mac OS 10.6 Snow Leopard and I'm trying to add a directory to my PATH variable so I can run a tiny script I wrote by just typing: python alarm.py at the terminal prompt.

I put the path in my .profile file and it seems to show up when I echo $PATH, but python still can't find script the that I've put in that directory.

Here's the contents of my .profile file in my home directory:

```
~ toby$ vim .profile 
export PATH=/Users/tobylieven/Documents/my_scripts:$PATH
```

Here's the output of echo $PATH, where all seems well:

```
~ toby$ echo $PATH
/Users/tobylieven/Documents/my_scripts:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Here's the script I'm trying to run:

```
~ toby$ ls /Users/tobylieven/Documents/my_scripts 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 tobylieven  staff  276 17 Jan 21:17 alarm.py
```

Here's the command I'm trying to use to run the script and the fail message I'm getting instead:

```
~ toby$ python alarm.py 
python: can't open file 'alarm.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If anyone has an idea what I might be doing wrong, that'd be great. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PATH is only for executables, not for python scripts. Add the following to the beginning of your Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and run

```
sudo chmod a+x /Users/tobylieven/Documents/my_scripts/alarm.py
```

Then, you can type just `alarm.py` to execute your program.

Comment: Awesome! It works :). Thanks a lot :D. Just so people know, you type '#' on a macbook pro by pressing alt+3.

Answer (score 6):

## Which python are you targeting?

#### Did you install it with brew? It uses a different path.

`which python3` or `which python`

Choose the one you want

Copy that output

Paste it at the top of your python file

add a `#!` in front of that path so it looks something like

#### `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Make sure to change the file permissions

#### `chmod +x filename`

Put that file in a folder that is in your path

#### Not sure if your folder is in your path?

`echo $path`

#### How to add that folder to your path?

Find your path first

`echo $HOME`

If you are using bash or zsh you might have something like this

In `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` at the bottom of your file

`export PYTHON_UTILS="$HOME/code/python/utils"`

`export PATH="$PYTHON_UTILS:$PATH"`

Consider removing the `.py` from your file bc it is not needed in this case

Close and open your terminal, which is sourcing your file by its path

And now you should be able to treat your python file similar to a bash command

You don't need to use `python3 filename.py` to run the file, you can just use `filename`

#### From anywhere on your filesystem!

Answer (score 5):

change alarm.py to include:

```
#!/bin/python
```

as the very first line in the file.

(or /usr/bin/python, depending on where you python interpreter is located.  You can figure this out by typing: `which python` in the terminal.)

You can then just run `alarm.py` instead of `python alarm.py`.

e.g.:

```
~ toby$ alarm.py
```

And phihag who beat me by a few seconds is right, you need to add execute permissions (via chmod) to alarm.py.

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify the Python specific path variable: PYTHONPATH.

So:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/tobylieven/Documents/my_scripts
```

should get you working.

See: [Python Module Search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Answer (score -1):

Something of interest that I really struggled with on OS X coming from Window, is that you its very hard to get the directory of your current script.

I found this.

```
#! /bin/zsh 
cd "${0:h}"
```

Now you could execute a python file relative to the executed script instead of having to know the exact path where your python file is.
This might or might not help but I use this a lot to make my scripts and .command files work better.