# Why can I only run my python from terminal on Mac OS X from my home directory?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, path

When I run my .py files from terminal on my Mac OS X El Capitan by typing `python <filename>.py` from home directory `/Users/username/Desktop`, it works fine, but when I run the same command for the same .py file located in a subfolder `/Users/username/Destop/subfolder`, it does not work, it says that cannot import the module I have in the .py file.

My `.bash_profile` has the following line

```
if which -s brew ; then
    #PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
    #PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
fi
```

When I type `which python`, it gives `/usr/local/bin/python`. The modules import fine if I enter python by typing 'python' on terminal giving

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
```

with the following sys.path

```
 ['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', ...]
```

When I test the sys.path on running a `python script.py` with the following code

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

on terminal, I get

```
['/Users/username/Desktop/subfoler', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', ...]
```

What should I modify so that I can run python directly in the subfolder on terminal by typing `python <filename>.py`?

Comment: Add '.' which is current directory to your PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! where should I add it to? Do i need to add it every time I ran it from a subdirectory or can I add it to PATH somewhere so that it is permanent?

Comment: Make it permanent.

Comment: how to make it permanent??

Comment: For example, in your .bash_profile PATH=".:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work..

Comment: Where is the module you want to import to the python script?

Comment: Try this, maybe it could help. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4718071/5504999

Comment: Thanks! can i do some modification to my .bash_profile so that I don't have to add the extra line to all my python scripts?

Comment: I am not sure where the modules are located, but these are the standard modules (matplotlib, numpy, scipy). It was at once working fine but did not work anymore.